# Installing Pandoc in Windows 7 using R

Tags: r, windows-7, pandoc

I'm trying to install `Pandoc` on `Windows 7` from `R 3.1.1` using `installr` package. I used the following code:

```
library(installr)
install.pandoc()
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") : unsupported URL scheme
```

How can I resolve these errors?

Comment: I wonder if this question is lacking a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

please run:

```
setInternet2(TRUE)
```

And then try again.